# Lftp PASV incorrect?

Tags: ftp, lftp

When connecting to a `ftp` via terminal, everthing is fine.

When using `lftp` instead, I'm constantly getting timed out and can never sync the folder content. But why?

script.sh:

```
lftp -c "
debug
open $HOST
user $USER $PASS
lcd $FSOURCE
mirror --delete --verbose $FSOURCE $FTARGET
exit
"
```

Result: login is successful, but then getting an info about incorrect PASV mode, then then nothing ever happens.

```
...
<--- 230 User <username> logged in
---> PWD
<--- 257 "/" is the current directory
---> PBSZ 0
<--- 200 PBSZ 0 successful
---> PROT P
<--- 200 Protection set to Private
---> PASV
<--- 227 Entering Passive Mode (...).
---- Address returned by PASV seemed to be incorrect and has been fixed
---- Connecting data socket to (...) port 65242
```

I also tried `set ftp:passive-mode false` to force active mode. Result:

```
---> PORT ...
<--- 500 Illegal PORT command
---- Switching passive mode on
---> LIST
---> ABOR
---- Closing aborted data socket
---- Closing control socket
```

Answer (score 2):

It turned out normal `ftp` command via terminal was still successful. I could fix `lftp` preventing the use of ssl. Probably the ftp owner disabled this suddenly.

`set ftp:ssl-allow off;`